Two equivalent statements yielding different values when evaluated?
Assume $v_i$ and $v_j$ are tent functions.
We have the expression:
$$ \int^b_a v_iv_j'' dx  $$
Integrating by parts gives:
$$ \int^b_a v_iv_j'' dx  = -\int^b_a v'_j v_i' dx + [v_iv_j']^b_a $$
Now let's assume that $v_i(a) = v_i(b) = 0$ getting us:
$$ \int^b_a v_iv_j'' dx  = -\int^b_a v'_j v_i' dx$$
These functions are piecewise and so we have 3 cases, their supports overlap, match perefectly or don't overlap.
If the support does not overlap then RHS is 0.
If the supports overlap WLOG assume that they overlap on the region where v'_i ascends.
Then we get:
$$v'_j v'_i = c_j c_i$$
over $[a, |b-a|/2]$ ($c_i, c_j$ being the constant slopes) and $v'_j v'_i = 0$ everywhere else, by virtue of both being piece-wise linear.
If $i = j$ then we get:
$$ -\int^b_a v'_j v_i' dx = -\int^b_a (v_i')^2 dx$$
Which is not 0.
But since $v_j$ is piecewise linear, then $v_j'' = 0$ always, so the LHS should always be 0.
What am I missing? Where is my mistake?

The piece-wise linear and constraints $v_i(a)=v_i(b)=0$ make the $v_i$ not differentiable everywhere. hence you can't use the integration by part! see for example answers to this question.

piecewise linear function $v_j$'s derivative $v_j''\neq 0$ (in any L^p), it is producing Dirac functions.

When you use a theorem, like integration by parts in  the present case, always be sure to  read not only the formula but also the surrounding prose, which in this case will incliude an assumption that some things are differentiable. As you've learned here, the prose is needed to  make the theorem true; it's not just decoration or lomg-windedness.

The reason this doesn't work is because $v_i''$ doesn't exist over the whole interval $[a,b]$, as it is a piecewise linear function. The integral you are trying to evaluate can only be done piecewise (as a sum over the elements), and therefore the integration by parts should pick up additional internal boundary terms.
